# List of functions

Tags: lua

Following definitions print already the result of the functions in the table:

```
function plus1(zahl) print(zahl+1) end
function plus2(zahl) print(zahl+2) end
function plus3(zahl) print(zahl+3) end

-- already prints out 6,5,10
local tfunc={plus1(5),plus2(3),plus3(7)}
```

1. how can I avoid this?
2. how can I iterate through the functions with given parameters in the table? I would like to call the functions like:

   tfunc[1]

   to print out 6. But it does not work.

@pschulz, thanks to show me the way :

```
 local tfunc = {{plus1,5},{plus2,3},{plus3,7}}
 tfunc[i][1](tfunc[i][2])
```

allows to iterate with index i through the different functions with different args. The trick is tables with function name and args inside the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you table, you are currently storing nothing (or three nil). The table takes the return value of the function and since you are returning nothing, it gets nil.

What you have to do is store *functions*:

```
local tfunc = { 
    plus1,
    plus2,
    plus3
}
```

No you can call your functions like this:

```
tfunc[1](5)
```

On iterating: If i understand correctly, you want to do the following:

```
local tfunc = { 
    plus1,
    plus2,
    plus3
}
local tvalues = { 5, 3, 7 }
for i, func in ipairs(tfunc) do
    func(tvalues[i])
end
```

So you have to save your values in another table. There are more elegant ways to do this, i suggest you have a reading on [closures](http://www.lua.org/pil/6.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
local tfunc={plus1(5),plus2(3),plus3(7)}
```

Here you call the functions inside the table constructor.

So once you create your table you will print those values. As your function does not return anything tfunc remains empty.
You can either store the function call as a string and let Lua execute that string or you can save the function in the table without calling it. Then you need some way to get the function parameter zahl into your function call.

To me what you want to do makes no sense.
If you want to call it like `tfunc[1]` it will always print 6. So why not just call `print(6)`?

If you want to add 3 to a number you want to print, just call `print(number + 3)` e.g.
Your code will remain more readable and easier to understand if you don't move simple arrithmetics into an extra function.

Comment: the idea behind is an state machine which should execute different functions with different parameters, whenever the index is increased. Before I used : 

         if index==1 then plus1(5) end
         if index==2 then plus2(3) end
    ...

I thought would be nice to use a table for this functions with certain args...

Comment: have a look at the load function if you want to execute predefined function calls. you can do something like load("plus1(5)")()